# Is this language regular or not?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

$$L = \big\{ (0^{m^2})^* \ \big \vert \ m \ge 1 \big\}\,.$$

I've given answer as regular but i am not sure. How? Please explain.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? If the language is regular, you should be able to construct an automaton for it - did you manage to do so? What techniques are you familiar with to prove that a language is *not* regular?

Comment: I think if i put m= 1,2,3,...... then L will be {(0^1, 0^4, 0^9,....)* }. and it will be generate (0*) so it can be regular.

Answer (score 5):

Hint. Consider $m=1$ and the question answers itself.